# How will a different form of DNA works?

Tags: creature-design, genetics

Most species of living organisms have double helix DNA, can there be a tesseract DNA? What benefits does this form of DNA have over the common helix form? Will this form of DNA unique to 5 or higher dimensions being?

Comment: As cool as that idea sounds, it would be more realistic to find organisms whose DNA is not solely composed of the 4 ATGC components but something more like ATBDEF.

Comment: @Neil in reality the new alphabet soup reads [ATGCXY](http://www.popularmechanics.com/science/health/a10512/x-y-scientists-create-two-new-letters-for-dna-16769967/)

Comment: As I understand it, the Tesseract cannot fill the role of DNA. However, the gem in Loki's scepter can take the place of a brain. You might try that.

Comment: @Jonah unfortunately neither I have the strength and power nor the courage to pull out the tesseract from Vision, the current owner.

Comment: @Neil my pleasure

Comment: The odds of someone with the biochemical knowledge required to understand the implications of changing the fundamental, microscopic base of life stopping in here is not great.  If would also be good to define *tesseract DNA*

Comment: @James no doubt about it, however having lingers in this community for some time and my instinct tells me don't count the chicken before they hatch

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: **No, there can't be a tesseract-shaped DNA equivalent.**

One of the key properties of the double helix that DNA forms is that it is a *linear* structure: it is a natural format for encoding information, since you can start at one end, read the pairs in order, and then stop when you reach the other end. It can be easily expanded or contracted to match the data you need to encode - just make it longer or shorter.

The tesseract is completely different; it has only 16 natural locations for data-points, there is no obvious start or end point, no obvious way to order the points...

It *might* be possible to come up with an alien life-form that uses a tesseract for some fundamental part of it's biology, but it's going to have to be so different in the way it functions that it would make no sense to call it 'tesseract DNA'.